# Procedure hangs querying tables in dblink

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, sqlplus, dblink

I'm trying to call a procedure from a shell script, that procedure makes a massive insert into my database with data of a remote database. So, what i'm doing here is querying tables through a dblink and inserting that information in my local tables.

When i do that directly from a DB IDE, like Quest Toad or Oracle SQL Developer, the procedure runs in less than 3 mins. When i run the procedure in sqlplus command line runs in less than 3 mins too. But when i call the procedure using a shell script, the process in unix hangs out, producing an high usage network event in oracle server and db session never ends.

So, the thing here is that i have another procedures running in the same way than this, and only this is causing issues while i execute in a ksh script.

Below, two approachs i'm using to call the procedure from sqlplus in the ksh script:

Original script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

PROFILE=/home/user/config/my_profile.sh
. ${PROFILE}
yesterday=$(TZ=GMT+24 date "+%d/%m/%Y")
echo "Establishing a DB connection"
/home/oraclei/product/11.1.0/bin/sqlplus<<END_OF_SQL
$USER/$PASSWD
execute MY_PROCEDURE@DB('$yesterday');
exit;
END_OF_SQL
```

Alternative:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

PROFILE=/home/user/config/my_profile.sh
. ${PROFILE}
echo "Establishing a DB connection"
yesterday=$(TZ=GMT+24 date "+%d/%m/%Y")
/home/oraclei/product/11.1.0/bin/sqlplus $USER/$PASSWD @/home/user/dblink_load/scripts/sql/load.sql $yesterday
```

and the sql script it uses

```
exec MYSCHEMA.MY_PROCEDURE('&1');
quit;
```

The queries in the procedure are something like this:

```
insert into MYSCHEMA.mytable
(id, date, stat1, stat2, stat3)
(select
    id, date, max(stat1), avg(stat2), avg(stat3)
from
    tableA@dblink table1,
    tableB@dblink table2,
    tableC@dblink table3
where
    table1.date >= parameter and
    table1.id = table2.id and
    table2.id = table3.id
group by
    table1.id,
    table1.date);
```

Comment: guessing: your script does not have the same environment and is failing to connect to the db correctly?

Comment: Do all environments use the same date format?  Your parameter may not be converted the same way each time.  You can check your session settings with a query like this: `select sys_context('userenv', 'nls_date_format') from dual;`

Comment: @Randy no, i'm using a copy of this script to call another procedure in the same database that query through same db link and it works fine

Comment: @jonearles Both local and remote database returns "DD/MM/RR" as result

Comment: @joeygs What about when you run it in Toad, SQL Developer, or SQL*Plus?  In Oracle, the date format is set by the client, not the server.

Comment: @jonearles SQL*PLUS: "DD/MM/RR", TOAD and SQL Developer "DD-MM-RRRR HH24:MI:SS"